# Splitting data into two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large Excel spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: [What it currently looks like](http://puu.sh/lpsyk/382e7fd3f6.png)]

However, I want to move every cell in the second column that starts with Location to the next column.

So it would look like this:

[image: [What I want it to look like](http://puu.sh/lpsDY/482be92bce.png)]

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

No need of VBA
Enter this formula in `C2` and copy till last record

```
=IF(LEFT(B3,9)="Location:",B3,"")
```

Then copy paste values in column `C`, filter column `B` for `Location:*` and clear the resulting cells in column `B` or delete the rows (do as needed).

Comment: When I try to filter it, should it be "does not contain: Location"? and when I do that, it affects the data in column C as well (cannot see locations anymore).

Comment: 1) enter the formula in column `C` 2) Copy Paste values in column `C` (so when you clear the cells in column `B` this is not affected as you have now the values and no the formulas) 3) Filter column `B` with Location (the Location value still there as you have not done anything as yet to this column 4) Do as you need i.e. delete the entire rows or clear the contents of the filtered cells in column `B`

Answer (score -1):

I would copy column B, paste it in column C then select C1 and press ctrl-- (CTRL and Minus together)

Select shift cells up and click OK.

Then either sort by column A or filter out any with a blank in column A.

Comment: Yes and you want it to be deleted, by shifting up in column C, B3 is now in C2 also

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Location",B2)),B2,"")
```

[image: P1]

Then apply conditional formatting to your data range as following:
[image]

**Final Result**

[image]